# Viber Callback Signature with HMAC

Tags: php, laravel, viber-api

I have been following the documentation in the Viber REST API to create a signature with HMAC using SHA256 [Callack Section](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#callbacks). The key is authentication token and the value is a json. I tried to create the signature using `hash_hmac` in PHP language but to no avail. I keep getting different results. I tried to beautify and adjust the structure of json but to no avail.

What I've Done:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $value = $request->getContent();
    $value = hash_hmac("sha256", $value, '4453b6ac12345678-e02c5f12174805f9-daec9cbb5448c51f');

    return $value;
}

Returned Result: 99b1988ed94ea0e336f5d670c5c71c793bd72f0bb65af2ccbe1f943cae23488c
```

Key:

```
4453b6ac12345678-e02c5f12174805f9-daec9cbb5448c51f
```

Json:

```
{  
   "event":"delivered",
   "timestamp":1457764197627,
   "message_token":491266184665523145,
   "user_id":"01234567890A="
}
```

Correct Result Should Be:

```
9d3941b33d45c165400d84dba9328ee0b687a5a18b347617091be0a56d
```

Comment: Are you actually getting that exact same JSON the docs gave as an example? Or are you testing this with actual incoming webhook data?

Comment: the signature will vary greatly even if a single space/newline is out of place. Have you tried this code to see if it works anyway if you send the correct body with matching signature?

Comment: @CBroe Currently, I am trying to get the Output result provided in that documentation with same Key and JSON before I try it with any other callback data. However, to no avail. I did try adjusting the json like by moving/removing the spaces - putting 1, 2, 3 lines before each field in json.

Comment: @apokryfos Yeah that's what I did. I keep rearranging the json value but can't seem to get that exact structured Json.  I did just copy and paste the Json and tested it in Postman - was not able to get the correct output/result.

Comment: That's not what I was saying though. I'm suggesting you send the request to the API with whatever signature you are getting anyway and check to see if it works. It's possible their output in the docs is an example value and not the actual matching value for that input

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert the content into string first.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJQi0.png)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! When answering questions, please provide code snippets inside a codeblock, instead of uploading a screenshot. This is so that the code is more accessible. Please also improve the quality of your answer, by explaining why your code works _in detail_. This helps the community understand the issue/solution better.